# mapping tool for ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

Currently, I'm making mapping manually (by code) between DTO's and state entities. I mean:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: true })
userLogin$: Observable<Action> = this._actions$
  .ofType('USER_LOGIN')
  .switchMap((action: Action) =>
    this._userService.checkPasswd(action.payload.username, action.payload.password)
      .map((user: UserDTO) => {
        return { type: 'USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: <IUser>{ id:user.id, cname:user.cname, sname:user.sname, username:user.username } };
      })
      .catch((err: ApiError) => {
        //...
      })
);
```

As you can see:

```
payload: <IUser>{ id:user.id, cname:user.cname, sname:user.sname, username:user.username }
```

I'd like to get it a bit more ellegantly, and using any mapping library or tool. Nevertheless, there's any best practice which would be enought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution for this that worked for us is using Typescript decorators to model the DTO class and define mapping rules yourself.
Here is something that can give you pointers:

[json-typescript-mapper](https://github.com/jf3096/json-typescript-mapper)

[TypedJSON](https://github.com/JohnWeisz/TypedJSON)

You basically need to annotate the class and attributes to make most scenarios work without much hassle. But for advance types it may require custom serializer and deserializer. Its not hard but will require some coding.